# Guice Explicit Bindings Not Matching

Tags: classloader, guice

I have a strange problem with Guice not using the explicit binding defined in a Guice Module. It's a simple mapping of an Interface to a Class.

I have followed it via the debugger and can see in the InjectorImpl.findBindingsByType() the bindings MultiMap does contain the binding in question. However it returns null and then throws an exception that no implementation is bound (see below).  The bound type is an interface so clearly it can't new it without using the binding.

```
1) No implementation for org.example.module.approval.ApprovalController was bound.
  Did you mean?
    org.example.module.approval.ApprovalController bound  at org.example.module.ApBaseModule.configure(ApBaseModule.kt:88)

    org.example.module.approval.ApprovalControllerImpl bound  at org.example.module.approval.ApprovalControllerImpl.class(Unknown Source)

  while locating org.example.module.approval.ApprovalController
    for the 1st parameter of org.example.module.invoices.delegates.BeginApprovalDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.example.module.invoices.delegates.BeginApprovalDelegate
```

I have tried using the Execute Expression tool in the debugger to call the equals methods on the TypeLiteral and the MultiMap entry it should match. This does return false. However I can't figure out why. Interestingly if I call toString on each and test the equality it returns true.

The JavaDocs I found don't specify the equality criteria for a Type Literal and I am struggling to follow the logic in the Guice source. What is it testing besides the conical name of the class? Does the Class Loader come into it?

The reason I ask is that the effected class is stored inside a separate "plugin" jar which my app loads via a Child Class Loader at startup. So it's a different class loader to most of the app.

Any suggestions regarding where to look next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have managed to work around my problem. It turned out the class that was doing the plugin loading was being run a second time due to a misconfigured dependancy referencing an implementation rather than an interface. Fixing that stopped my issue. So I can only assume that the Class Loader does impact the type matching.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It's always a good idea to post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it so everyone can see that this is solved. Thanks!

Comment: To be perfectly honest, just because I made it work, I am not confident I have learnt anything about why it didn't work. Clearly I didn't want to be running this code twice. However I don't actually understand why it helped. I was hoping someone who is familiar with the Class Loaders and Types would be able to answer the question with an explanation.